# What's the HTML tag for the "Chinese dollar" currency symbol?

Tags: html, character-encoding

What HTML tag represents the symbol for Chinese currency?

Or is there such a tag?

Comment: What 'tag' are you talking about? Not programming related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean HTML entity for ¥:

```
&yen;
```

[Handy reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Comment: Check out this answer for a good rundown on the different options for representing the Chinese yuan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642468/chinese-yuan-cny-currency-symbol-in-html

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_yuan):

> Shop prices in mainland China and Taiwan are usually marked with 元 after the digits. In mainland China, using '￥' as well as RMB to denote the currency is common.

And [here's the link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a5/index.htm) on how to get the ￥ character in unicode or with HTML entities.

Comment: On the mainland I've never seen the ￥ symbol outside financial institutions.  It's always RMB or more likely 元.  Admittedly most what I have seen is Shanghai and nearby locations.

Comment: @Loren: Okay, who's going to put the [citation needed] tag on the Wikipedia page then? :)

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese use the [Renminbi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renminbi), sometimes denoted as RMB.  It's also called the Yuan.

Answer (score 1):

I think you possibly want CNY (ie. Chinese yuan). Also sometimes known as RMB.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renminbi

Answer (score 0):

The symbol they use is Unicode & # 5 1 4 3 ; which is suffixed, not prefixed, to the amount e.g. 100元

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)**.

```js
var number = 12.80;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('zh-CN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'CNY'
}).format(number));
```