# Chinese Yuan (CNY currency symbol) in HTML?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the HTML tag for the “Chinese dollar” currency symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275798/whats-the-html-tag-for-the-chinese-dollar-currency-symbol)

What is the html code/entities for chinese yuan(CNY), is it similar to JPY, ¥?
I did not found any solution and i don't know the Chinese language. And also can I use RMB before amount?

Comment: Isn't that a question best answered by a translator? Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_yuan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669075/how-to-find-out-the-html-code-for-a-currency

Comment: the question's been closed so I can't answer it.  the Chinese use this symbol: &#5143; and suffix it to values (it gets appended not prepended to the amount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People would understand RMB, Wikipedia says you can use ¥ (same as for Japanese yen), but 元 seems to be more common than that, at least "offline" in real-world shops.

If you can use Unicode, just copy/paste the character in from somewhere (like here).

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A5):

> ¥ is a currency sign used by the Japanese yen (JPY) and the Chinese yuan (CNY) currencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JPY ¥ for Chinese Yuan as well.
For example ¥50.00